# Using Celery to store class instantiated object

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am new to Celery & Python and have cursory knowledge of both. 
I have multiple Ubuntu servers which all run multiple Celery workers(10 - 15).
Each of these workers need to perform a certain task using a third party libraries/DLL. For that we first 
need to instantiate their class object and store it (somehow in memory). 
Then the Celery workers read RMQ queues to execute certain tasks which uses the above class object methods.
The goal is to instantiate the third party class object once (when celerty worker starts) and then on task execution,
use the class instance methods. Just keep doing this in repeatedly.

I don't want to use REDIS as it seems like too much overhead to store such tiny amount of data(class object). 
I need help in figuring out how to store this instantiated class object per worker. If the worker fails or crashes, obviously, we instantiate the class again which is not a problem. Any help specifically code sample will help a lot.

To provide more analogy, my requirement is similar to having a unique database connection per worker and using the same connection every repeated request. 
Updated with some poorly written code for that:

tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery, Task

#Declares the config file and this worker file
mycelery = Celery('tasks')
mycelery.config_from_object('celeryconfig2')

class IQ(Task):
        _db = None

        @property
        def db(self):
                if self._db is None:
                        print 'establish DB connection....'
                        self._db = Database.Connect()
                return self._db

@mycelery.task(base=IQ)
def indexIQ():
        print 'calling indexing.....'
        if index.db is None:
                print 'DB connection doesn't exist. Let's create one...'
        ....
        ....

        print 'continue indexing!'
```

main.py

```
from tasks import *
indexIQ.apply_async()
indexIQ.appply_async()
indexIQ.appply_async()
print 'end program'
```

Expected output

```
calling indexing.....
DB connection doesn't exist. Let's create one...
establish DB connection....
continue indexing!
calling indexing.....
continue indexing!
calling indexing.....
continue indexing!
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the 1st 4 lines of output all the time which means the DB connection is happening at each task execution. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: This is too broad.

Comment: I modified the original text. Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?